# Hackerrank problem (Post Transition) (C) What's causing this seg fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I've been trying to solve this problem on hackerrank
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/post-transition
but my code seems to yield a segmentation fault when I try to run it.
I've gone over it a couple dozen times already and have compared it to other people's solution and I still can't wrap my head around what I might be doing wrong.

*Here is the error message I'm getting :*

```
  Reading symbols from Solution...done.

[New LWP 1602418]

[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Core was generated by `./Solution'.

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

#0  send_all_acceptable_packages (source=source@entry=0x16eeec8, 
    source_office_index=0, target=target@entry=0x16eeee0, 
    target_office_index=<optimized out>) at Solution.c:58
58      int src_pk_count = (source->offices[source_office_index].packages_count);
```

**Here is my code**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 6

struct package
{
    char* id;
    int weight;
};

typedef struct package package;

struct post_office
{
    int min_weight;
    int max_weight;
    package* packages;
    int packages_count;
};

typedef struct post_office post_office;

struct town
{
    char* name;
    post_office* offices;
    int offices_count;
};

typedef struct town town;



void print_all_packages(town t)
{
    printf("%s:\n",t.name);

    //offices loop
   for(int i=0;i<t.offices_count;i++)
   {
       printf("\t%i:\n",i);

       //packages loop
       for(int j=0;j<t.offices[i].packages_count;j++)
        {printf("\t\t%s\n", t.offices[i].packages[j].id);}
   }


}

void send_all_acceptable_packages
(town* source, int source_office_index, town* target, int target_office_index)

{

    int trg_pk_count = (target->offices[target_office_index].packages_count);
    int src_pk_count = (source->offices[source_office_index].packages_count);
   
    //weight condition
    
    int min_w = (target->offices[target_office_index].min_weight);
    int max_w = (target->offices[target_office_index].max_weight);
     

   for(int i=0;i<src_pk_count;i++)
    {


        int pckg_w = (source->offices[source_office_index].packages[i].weight);


        if ((pckg_w >= min_w) && (pckg_w <= max_w))
        {
            
         
            
             target->offices[target_office_index].packages = realloc                                 (target->offices[target_office_index].packages, sizeof(package)*                           (trg_pk_count+1));                 
             
            (target->offices[target_office_index].packages_count)++;
            (source->offices[source_office_index].packages_count)--;
             
             
                   
             target->offices[target_office_index].packages[(trg_pk_count)]=                           source->offices[source_office_index].packages[i];



             for(int x=0; x<(src_pk_count-1);x++)
             {
             source->offices[source_office_index].packages[i+x] = source->offices                     [source_office_index].packages[i+x+1] ;
             
             
             source->offices[source_office_index].packages= realloc(source->offices                   [source_office_index].packages, sizeof(package)*((source->offices                        [source_office_index].packages_count)));
             }
            

        }

            

    }
 
}


town town_with_most_packages(town* towns, int towns_count)
{
    //count
    int town_pkcount[towns_count];

    for(int i=0;i<towns_count;i++)
    {
        town_pkcount[i]=0;
        int sum=0;
        for(int j=0;j<towns[i].offices_count;j++)
        {

            sum+= towns[i].offices[j].packages_count;
        }


        town_pkcount[i]=sum;
    }

   //find max
   int max=-1 , max_index;
   for(int i=0; i<towns_count;i++)
   {
       if (town_pkcount[i]>max)
       {
           max = town_pkcount[i];
           max_index=i;
       }


   }


   return towns[max_index];


}

town* find_town(town* towns, int towns_count, char* name)
{
    int town_index=-1;
    for(int i=0; i<towns_count; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(name,towns[i].name)==0)
        {town_index = i;}


        break;
    }



    return(&towns[town_index]);


}

int main()
{
    int towns_count;
    scanf("%d", &towns_count);
    town* towns = malloc(sizeof(town)*towns_count);
    for (int i = 0; i < towns_count; i++) {
        towns[i].name = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
        scanf("%s", towns[i].name);
        scanf("%d", &towns[i].offices_count);
        towns[i].offices = malloc(sizeof(post_office)*towns[i].offices_count);
        for (int j = 0; j < towns[i].offices_count; j++) {
            scanf("%d%d%d", &towns[i].offices[j].packages_count, &towns[i].offices[j].min_weight, &towns[i].offices[j].max_weight);
            towns[i].offices[j].packages = malloc(sizeof(package)*towns[i].offices[j].packages_count);
            for (int k = 0; k < towns[i].offices[j].packages_count; k++) {
                towns[i].offices[j].packages[k].id = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
                scanf("%s", towns[i].offices[j].packages[k].id);
                scanf("%d", &towns[i].offices[j].packages[k].weight);
            }
        }
    }
    int queries;
    scanf("%d", &queries);
    char town_name[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    while (queries--) {
        int type;
        scanf("%d", &type);
        switch (type) {
        case 1:
            scanf("%s", town_name);
            town* t = find_town(towns, towns_count, town_name);
            print_all_packages(*t);
            break;
        case 2:
            scanf("%s", town_name);
            town* source = find_town(towns, towns_count, town_name);
            int source_index;
            scanf("%d", &source_index);
            scanf("%s", town_name);
            town* target = find_town(towns, towns_count, town_name);
            int target_index;
            scanf("%d", &target_index);
            send_all_acceptable_packages(source, source_index, target, target_index);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Town with the most number of packages is %s\n", town_with_most_packages(towns, towns_count).name);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*keep in mind that the structs and the main function were already pre-written*

The seg fault seems to have something to do with the *send_all_acceptable_packages* function

Also keep in mind that the seg fault happens after entering this line of input
*2 B 0 A 1*
which triggers case 2 in main

```
  case 2:
            scanf("%s", town_name);
            town* source = find_town(towns, towns_count, town_name);
            int source_index;
            scanf("%d", &source_index);
            scanf("%s", town_name);
            town* target = find_town(towns, towns_count, town_name);
            int target_index;
            scanf("%d", &target_index);
            send_all_acceptable_packages(source, source_index, target, target_index);
            break;
```

where you can see that the return value from the *find_town* function is used as input for the *send_all_acceptable_packages* function which leads me to believe the fault lies within one of these two functions

Please help me identify the issue here, I'd appreciate your input.

Comment: No idea if this is an issue (too much code), but in `find_town` if nothing is found, you are using a negative index (-1).

Comment: Have _you_ run it in debug mode yet?

Comment: @ryyker Still going over that

Comment: @JohnnyMopp hmm idk it might lead to bugs with certain cases of input but it this particular case the function is supposed is supposed to find a town so the -1 won't have any effect

Comment: In `find_town()`, the following is flagged as  _will never be executed_:  `int town_index=-1;
    for(int i=0; i<towns_count; i++)`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Actually I've just tried this and you were right. The code compiled after I changed it to 0 which leads me to believe the find_town function isn't doing it's job right.

Comment: @ryyker Yes thank you . That is indeed the source of the seg fault. any idea how I can fix this function?

Comment: Also, in `town_with_most_packages()`, it is possible that `max_index` can be uninitialized in this statement: `return towns[max_index];`

Comment: In `find_town` the `break` needs to be inside the `if` block.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you! This solved the issue with the find_town function but the program still seems to generate incorrect output. I'll try and figure out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You do not check `malloc` for `NULL`. You do not check if `scanf` failed. `scanf("%s"` does not protects against overflow. - any imput longer then 5 chars will break. Allocating constant amount of data is odd - it could have been just `char name[6];`. `int town_pkcount[towns_count];` is a VLA - it does not protect against allocation failure. You do not free memory.

Comment: Remove the `break` statement from the `fined_town()` loop.  The `break` statement guarantees the loop will never iterate.  (that is the purpose of a `break`)

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes you are right and I'm well aware that the program is full of faults. But like I said I did not write main() and I'm merely just trying to solve a challenge on hackerrank where the given task is to write code for all the missing functions and I'm pretty sure that the input test cases used by the site to evaluate the program are designed to neglect all these issues and just check if the code for the function I've been assigned to complete behaves correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop in the following will never iterate:

```
town* find_town(town* towns, int towns_count, char* name)
{
    int town_index=-1;
    int i = 0;
    
    for(i=0; i < towns_count; i++)<-warning points here (i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(name,towns[i].name)==0)
        { town_index = i;}   
        break;<- cause of warning
    }
    return(&towns[town_index]);
}
```

I see the following warning from my debugger:

> 150, 31    warning: will never be executed

The break statement guarantees the loop will never iterate.

You probably intended for it to be inside the `if()` statement

```
town* find_town(town* towns, int towns_count, char* name)
{
    int town_index=-1;
    int i = 0;
    
    for(i=0; i < towns_count; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(name,towns[i].name)==0)
        { 
            town_index = i;
            break;
        }   
        
    }
    return(&towns[town_index]);
}
```

A few additional items to look at:

- `int main(void);` is the minimum prototype for the `main` function in `C` ( not `int main()`)
- code does not check the returns of function(s) that should always be checked (eg `scanf()`).
- It would be better to limit the input length for the calls to `scanf()` to prevent overflows, i.e. with `#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 6`, the user is limit to some very short names, but if city is entered as "Dallas"  `scanf("%s", towns[i].name);` program will overflow.  Write it as `scanf("%(MAX_STRING_LENGTH-1)s", towns[i].name);` to limit user input to a legal length.
- Suggest changing `#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 6` to a more realistic value.
- Memory leaks.   Code frees none of the memory created.  Use call to `free()` once for each call to `malloc()`
- use `printf()` prior to each `scanf()` to list instructions for user input. (eg: `printf("enter town name\n");` )